# How to get the value of a Excel control in a C# app

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I know how to access an excel cell value in C#.

But how to obtain the value of a control ? (checkbox, radiobutton, and so)

I googled it and found nothing related, is there a way to do that ? I'm using EPPlus but the library doesn't have support for controls :/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The only thing more frustrating than working with Excel-interop is working with the OpenXML-SDK.